How to plot large dataset of Shapely LineString with Plotly?
I've been given a DXF file at work to analyse it, and they want me to plot it as well. This file contains a layout of a private area. The data looks like this:
Layer   PaperSpace    SubClasses              Linetype  EntityHandle Text  geometry
860     0       None  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline     None          59E  None  LINESTRING (441.981 186.290, 441.981 189.994, 441.599 189.993, 441.599 186.289, 441.980 186.289)
861     0       None  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline     None          59F  None  LINESTRING (441.981 193.740, 441.981 190.036, 441.599 190.036, 441.599 193.740, 441.980 193.740)
862     0       None  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline     None          5A0  None      LINESTRING (441.790 189.994, 441.790 190.036)
863     0       None  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline     None          5A1  None      LINESTRING (441.790 190.015, 441.790 190.015)
864     0       None  AcDbEntity:AcDbPolyline     None          5A2  None      LINESTRING (441.790 186.544, 441.790 186.544)

The whole dataset has 397.535 records. The column I'm interested is the geometry one, which is full of Shapely LineString objects. Even if I can plot it without issues with GeoPandas plot, I want to be able to plot the geometry column with Plotly (since this allow me to zoom in, out, see values when hovering over the plot, etc.). However, I cannot plot the whole dataset without having VSCode or the browser (I tried Jupyter Notebook on web and also tried to open an html file generated with fig.write_html, with no success) to crash.
This is the whole code (partially adapted to be able to run it):
import plotly.graph_objects as go

plot_data = []

sample_coords = [[[441.9805811878579, 441.9805811878579, 441.5995787878578, 441.5995787878578, 441.9805811878579], [186.2897580001509, 189.9939480001509, 189.9939480001509, 186.2897580001509, 186.2897580001509]], 
[[441.9805811878579, 441.9805811878579, 441.5995787878578, 441.5995787878578, 441.9805811878579], [193.7404716001509, 190.0362816001509, 190.0362816001509, 193.7404716001509, 193.7404716001509]], 
[[441.7900799878579, 441.7900799878579], [189.9939480001509, 190.0362816001509]], 
[[441.7900799878579, 441.7900799878579], [190.0151148001509, 190.0151148001509]], 
[[441.7900799878579, 441.7900799878579], [186.5437596001509, 186.5437596001509]]]

for x, y in sample_coords:
  #x, y = linestring.xy
  #print(y)
  plot_data.append(
      go.Scatter(
          x=x,
          y=y,
          fill="toself",  # Fills the linestring
          mode="none",  # Hides markers
          showlegend=False
      )
  )

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1100,
    height=800,
    margin=go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=100, t=100, pad=4),
)

# Create the figure and display
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=layout)
fig.show()

For instance, plotting the head of said DataFrame produces this plot:


Your wording is a bit confusing. You refer to LineStrings in the title while your code talks about Polygons. Not to mention that this one (by iterating over polyline_df.geometry) gives an empty plot. Can you take a step back and see how to make a Minimal Reproducible Example ?

You also may want to take a step back and consider what you should be using to approach the problem. Are you trying to use Plotly's render_mode argument? Are you insisting on Plotly? See here, here, and maybe see about jupyter-scatter?

@Timeless thanks for your comment, I've tweaked the question a bit so you can see the right plot

@Wayne thanks for your links, I'll look into them and come back with an answer
